How logout a gocloak admin session
I created an login with gocloak like this:
client := gocloak.NewClient(url)
ctx := context.Background()

// Retrieve a token
token, err := client.LoginAdmin(ctx, username, password, realm)
if err != nil {
    log.Error("Failed to get token from keycloak. ", err.Error())
    log.Errorf("User: %s", config.username)
    return
}


But how do I logout the created session?
I've looked at some logout functions but they all require a clientsecret, which is what is not used with the adminlogin

Found it!! The clientSecret for client.Logout(ctx, "admin-cli", "", realm, token.RefreshToken)  can be an empty string
